# Concatenate strings, files and program output in Bash

Tags: bash, concatenation, stdout

The use case is, in my case, CSS file concatenation, before it gets minimized. To concat two CSS files:

```
cat 1.css 2.css > out.css
```

To add some text at *one single* position, I can do

```
cat 1.css <<SOMESTUFF 2.css > out.css
This will end in the middle.
SOMESTUFF
```

To add STDOUT from *one* other program:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/g' 3.css | cat 1.css - 2.css > out.css
```

So far so good. But I regularly come in situations, where I need to mix *several* strings, files and even program output together, like copyright headers, files preprocessed by `sed(1)` and so on. I'd like to concatenate them together in as little steps and temporary files as possible, while having the freedom of choosing the order.

In short, I'm looking for a way to do this in as little steps as possible in Bash:

```
command [string|file|output]+ > concatenated
# note the plus ;-) --------^
```

(Basically, having a `cat` to handle multiple STDINs would be sufficient, I guess, like

```
<(echo "FOO") <(sed ...) <(echo "BAR") cat 1.css -echo1- -sed- 2.css -echo2-
```

But I fail to see, how I can access those.)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This works:

```
cat 1.css <(echo "FOO") <(sed ...) 2.css <(echo "BAR")
```

Comment: D'oh! That's the simplest solution (in my case), so I'll accept this.

Comment: Of course @Boldewyn must've added `> concatenated.css` or `| compiler` at the end for it to work for his problem like this: `cat file1.css <(echo "FOO") <(command [string|file|output]) file2.css <(echo "BAR") > concatenated`

Answer (score 22):

You can do:

```
echo "$(command 1)" "$(command 2)" ... "$(command n)" > outputFile
```

Comment: You need to quote those command substitutions to preserve whitespace.

Answer (score 17):

You can add all the commands in a subshell, which is redirected to a file:

```
(
    cat 1.css
    echo "FOO"
    sed ...
    echo BAR
    cat 2.css
) > output
```

You can also append to a file with `>>`. For example:

```
cat 1.css  >  output
echo "FOO" >> output
sed ...    >> output
echo "BAR" >> output 
cat 2.css  >> output
```

(This potentially opens and closes the file repeatedly)

Comment: You can use a curly brace block to do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that'd do it, completely missed that option. +1.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, () is POSIX-compliant, whereas command-substitution is a bash extension, which was unimplemented in Cygwin Bash until about 2008.

Comment: @Leo, you are mistaken. Command substitution is absolutely specified in POSIX sh; see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03